# ¿Cómo reemplazar caracteres en archivos de texto?

Tags: c, archivo

Quiero realizar un programa que sustituya todas las ocurrencias de la letra a por un `*` en un archivo de texto.

Este es mi código:

```c
void sust_a(){
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("D:/Progra1/ejercicio8.txt","r+");
    char car;
    while (fscanf(arch,"%c",&car)!=EOF)
    {
        if (car=='a'){
            //fprintf(arch,"a");
            //fputs("*",arch);
            fseek(arch,0,SEEK_SET);
            fprintf(arch,"*");
            fputs("*",arch);
        }
    }
    fclose(arch);
}
void main()
{
    sust_a();
}
```

En mi bloc de notas tengo guardado: `aaaaaaaaaa`

y cuando se ejecuta me devuelve: `aaaa**aaaa`
(cuando utilizo fseek, pero cuando utilizo `fprintf(`...`)` no realiza nada)

¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no tengo un compilador de C a mano como para probarlo, pero estoy casi seguro que tu problema está en el fseek. Cuando usas la funcion fread, el "file pointer" se mueve automaticamente a la siguiente posición, asi que no es necesario que utilices la función fseek.

Este código debería funcionar:

```
void sust_a(void)
{
    FILE *arch;
    char car; 
    arch=fopen("D:/Progra1/ejercicio8.txt","r+");

    while (fscanf(arch,"%c",&car)!=EOF)
    {
        if (car=='a')
        {
            fprintf(arch,"*");    
        }
    }
    fclose(arch);
}
```

Además, el argumento SEEK_SET le dice a la función fseek que tome como referencia el comienzo del archivo, en tu caso le estás diciendo que se mueva 0 posiciones desde el comienzo, por lo tanto escribiría siempre sobre el primer caracter.

Una correcta utilización de la funcion fseek en este caso, hubiera sido utilizar el argumento SEEK_CUR, para que el file pointer se mueva 0 posiciones desde el lugar donde se encuentra ubicado actualmente.

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias :), pero aun asi no me funciona...

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código creo debería funcionar:

```
void sust_a(void)
{
    FILE *arch;
    char car; 
    arch=fopen("D:/Progra1/ejercicio8.txt","r+");
    if (!arch){
            perror("El archivo no se pudo abrir\n");
            return;
    }

    while (fscanf(arch,"%c",&car)!=EOF)
    {
        if (car=='a')
        {
            fseek(arch, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('*', arch);
            fflush(arch);
        }
    }
    fclose(arch);
}
```

Una vez que leíste el caracter que quieres reemplazar, deber regresar para posicionearte sobre ese mismo caracter pero para escribir, entonces escribes el caracter (reemplazando la 'a' por '*'). Debes finalizar con fflush, recuerda que debes limpiar el buffer de lectura (buffer interno de la biblioteca libc) ya que ha ocurrido una modificación en el archivo(con fputc). la llamada a fputc mueve el cursor a la siguiente posición, por lo tanto no es necesario moverlo con fseek. Espero esto resuelva tu problema.